# php remove @ from email before function not working

Tags: php

I am trying to remove the user ID of someone that has entered their email in a form with the `before` function [as shown in the following link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Basically, the form has a field called "email". Then I entered in a variable like this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Then I would like to have another variable that contains just the user ID. I am trying to do this with:

```
$userId = before ('@', $email);
```

But it is not working.

Comment: The `before` function from the comments is not a built-in function. Did you actually copy and paste their declarations into your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to use is strstr() function which you can read about [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
$email = "name@email.com"
$user = strstr($email, '@', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
echo $user; // prints name
```

Comment: It's nothing, I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

```
$email = "someone@example.com";
$username = explode("@", $email);
$username = $username[0];
echo $username; //$username will contain the username from the email
```

---

Or if you want to use `before ('@', $email);` add this to your code:

```
function before($needle, $str){
    $before = explode($needle, $str);
    return $before[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to remove the user ID of someone that has entered their
>   email in a form with the `before` function [as shown in the following
>   link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

There is no built in `before` function on PHP.

Your link is to the main [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) documentation page on the official PHP site. The `before` you refer to has 100% nothing to do with the [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function but comes from some custom functions [the user `biohazard` posted in the comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#112707) there:

> may be by following functions will be easier to extract the needed sub
>   parts from a string:

And looking at `biohazard`’s examples you would need to add this function to your codebase:

```
function before ($this, $inthat)
{
    return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $this));
};
```

But the problem with the functions presented is that they are really overkill in many cases. You are much better off doing direct [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) calls for your task unless you know for a fact you will be using the core logic of `before` in many different places. So just do this:

```
// Set a test e-mail.
$test_email = "foo@bar.com";

// Extract the user id from the e-mail using "@" as the delimiter.
$user_id = substr($test_email, 0, strpos($test_email, "@"));

// Echo the user id.
echo $user_id;
```

The returned `$user_id` would be `foo`.

The way that works is [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) takes the value of the e-mail & returns the value from `0` (the start of the string) to the `@` based on where [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) tells you the `@` is.